# How to install pdfBooklet-2.2.2 taz.gz in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and a layman in regard to computers in general so I need detailed information on how to install "pdfBooklet-2.2.2 tar.gz" to my machine using the terminal.

I tried the existing procedure but didn't work for me.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

PdfBooklet is a pyGTK utility to create booklets and other layouts from PDF documents. PdfBooklet can also merge files, extract pages, rotate and scale pages.

#### Installation in Ubuntu 14.04/16.04

1. Go to [ppa:ferramroberto/lffl](https://launchpad.net/%7Eferramroberto/+archive/ubuntu/lffl/) webpage.
2. Click the hyperlink that says: *View package details*.
3. Click the arrow to the left of the *pdfbooklet - 2.2.2-2~lffl~trusty* package to unfold the package's information.
4. Download the pdfbooklet_2.2.2-2~lffl~trusty_all.deb file.
5. Double-click the .deb file that you downloaded to open it for installation in the Software application.
6. The .deb file has two dependencies: python-poppler and python-gtk2. These dependencies will also be installed automatically from the default Ubuntu repositories when you install PdfBooklet.

#### Installation in Ubuntu 12.04

The installation is the same as for Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 except that instead of *pdfbooklet - 2.2.2-2~lffl~trusty* select *pdfbooklet - 2.2.2-2~lffl~precise* and download its .deb file.